# Unhandled promise rejection inside a catch

Tags: node.js, unhandled-promise-rejection

I'm getting the following error inside a catch:

> Blockquote
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originared either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, orby rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().

This is the code that invokes it:

```
http({
      method: 'post',
      url: config.uri,
      headers: headers,
      data: data
    }).then(function (response) {
      resolve(response.data);
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error.response.data);
      reject(error.response.data);
    });
```

The console.log call inside the catch reads: {status: 'ERROR', code: 'EMAIL_FAIL', message: 'Email fail to send' }

This code  that calls the function:

```
router.post('/declaration', csrf, async function (req, res, next) {
    let reqId = generateReqId();
    const ref = reqId.split('-')[0];
   let data = buildSubmission(fakeSub, res.locals.locale.toUpperCase(), ref);
    let headers = { ref: data.ref, reqId: reqId };
    const response = await callAPI.submitApplication(data, headers);

    casaApp.endSession(req).then(() => {
      res.status(302).render('../views/pages/confirmation.njk');
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(302).render('../views/pages/exit-error.njk');
    });
  });
```

Why am I getting this?
I want the code to return to the calling segment which will handle the  problem.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show us more code. `resolve` and `reject` are undefined in your snippet...

Comment: You are not catching the rejected promise when you call your async function.

Comment: Have added the calling function!

Comment: Catch is there for rejection, why are you calling reject() inside it. Please remove that.Plus that Reject is not defined anywhere.

Comment: Where are those `resolve` and `reject` functions that you're calling with your `http` method? If they don't exist, just simply do return response.data` inside the `then` callback and `throw error.response.data` inside the `catch` callback. You shouldn't be calling functions that are not defined. Additionally, make sure you're handling all your errors properly - use a `try/catch` like in the answer below and put everything in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your not catch errors from callAPI.submitApplication request:

```js
router.post('/declaration', csrf, async function (req, res, next) {
    const reqId = generateReqId();
    const ref = reqId.split('-')[0];
    const data = buildSubmission(fakeSub, res.locals.locale.toUpperCase(), ref);
    const headers = { ref: data.ref, reqId: reqId };
    try {
      const response = await callAPI.submitApplication(data, headers);
      await casaApp.endSession(req);
      res.status(302).render('../views/pages/confirmation.njk');
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(302).render('../views/pages/exit-error.njk');
    }
  });
```